# Is there a way to edit comments on the iPad app?

Tags: support, ios-app, ipad

I use the dictation feature on my iPad a lot in preference to the on-screen keyboard. The one drawback to this is that Siri sometimes mangles something I've said... Sometimes in a subtle way that isn't easily noticed at first.

I tried clicking on the three dots next to my comment, but didn't see an option to edit it. Did I miss something?

Comment: You can only edit comments within 5 minutes of posting them. Has that time elapsed? Otherwise, that is the correct place to edit them.

Comment: Ah, yes it probably was more than five minutes. And yes, I am successfully editing this comment right now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That is a network-wide rule, not much we can do there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only edit comments within 5 minutes of posting them. After that, the edit option will disappear from the menu that is shown from the accessory button (the three dots).